# Read/Write generic tiff tags using GDAL API

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

Is it possible to read/write generic tiff tags with GDAL?  I know some tags are supported (http://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html), but is there a way to access other tags?

For example, there are geo tags I would like to access directly.  If this is not currently supported are there future plans?

[image: Tiff Info]